# How to LInk Backend(Node.js) to front-End(React)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am starting out on React.js after learning Node.js using Express. But I don't know How to Link my Backend App to front end React files? Can someone provide me a simple solution to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can begin with this steps, you got a thousands of topics about to make a complete and solid infrastructure:

1. **Initialise your node.js server with port, cors (if you need)**
2. **Learn how express work with node.js and create your first route**
3. **Initialize your react project with or without npx create-react-app**
4. **Create your first frontend component and fetch data from your API**

Link : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-react-frontend-a-node-express-backend-and-connect-them-together-c5798926047c/